# Grey Box system identification using LMS algorithm

Tags: adaptive-filters, system-identification, lms, adaptive-algorithms

The transfer function and the input output data of the system are known. The transfer function is given by $$G(s) = \frac{K}{(Js+b)(Ls+R)+K^2}$$
How are the parameters of the transfer function determined using the LMS algorithm?

Should the number of weights of the LMS algorithm always be same as the number of parameters of the transfer function?

Any help on this is highly appreciated.